# Array turns back to its original form after being modified inside a function

Tags: java, arrays, function, pointers, reference

I was trying to do problem no. 189 in LeetCode but I encountered a problem. The code is as follows:

```java
public class Solution {
    public void rotate(int[] nums, int k) {
        k %= nums.length;
        int[] newArr = new int[nums.length];
        for(int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
            newArr[i + k] = nums[i];
        }
        for(int i = nums.length - k; i < nums.length; i++) {
            newArr[i - (nums.length - k)] = nums[i];
        }
        nums = newArr;
    }
//function above should shift each element of the array "nums" to "k" times right
//below is the main where I tried to check if it worked fine
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        Solution sol = new Solution();
        sol.rotate(nums, 3);
        for(int i : nums) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

After getting a console print exactly same as the original form of the nums array, I decided to do debug. rotate function works properly and indeed serves it purpose (i.e. after the `nums = newArr;` line, nums indeed become {5,6,7,1,2,3,4}). However I noticed that after the function is called in the main and finishes its execution, nums array is turned back to its original form ({1,2,3,4,5,6,7}) rather than staying {5,6,7,1,2,3,4}. I wonder what causes this? How can I keep the changes I made in the function to the array while keeping the return type of the function void?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your code instead of doing

```
nums = newArr;
```

as the last line of method rotate you should consider returning newArr and assiging new array/reassigning values:

```java
int[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
Solution sol = new Solution();
int[] result = sol.rotate(nums, 3);
for(int i : result) { System.out.println(i); }
```

```java
public int[] rotate(int[] nums, int k) {
    <...> //code omitted for brevity
    return newArr;
}
```

Second option (to preserve void return type) will be to treat *nums* array as resulting array (newArr). It will keep return type void and updates will be "visible" from main method

**Explanation:**
In Java, when an object reference (in this case array of ints) is passed to a method, a copy of the reference is created and passed to the method. This means that the method receives a new reference that points to the same object as the original reference, but it is not the same reference.

To understand this, consider the following example:

```java
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
        changeArr(arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
    
    public static void changeArr(int[] arr) {
        arr[0] = 0;
        arr = new int[] {4, 5, 6};
    }
}
```

In this example, an array arr is created and initialized with {1, 2, 3}. The changeArr method is then called, passing in a reference to arr.

Inside the changeArr method, the first element of arr is changed to 0, which modifies the original array. However, a new array {4, 5, 6} is created and the arr reference is updated to point to this new array.

When the method returns, the original reference arr still points to the modified array {0, 2, 3}, not to the new array {4, 5, 6}. This demonstrates that the reference passed to the method is different from the original reference, and that changes made to the object referred to by the reference are visible outside the method, but changes to the reference itself are not.

Comment: Hey @Le0pold, first of all thank you for your in-depth answer and taking your time. I think I now understand the problem. In the light of this, about my second question; there are no solutions that could be applied to achieve the same result without changing the return from void to int[] , am I correct?

Comment: Hey @Wiscoteju, I wanted to preserve your algorithm - that's why I changed return type. Inside rotate function you still have reference to original array of ints. This means that you need to modify nums inside rotate function